# UIImageView / UIButton autoresize to wrong frame value on second and consecutive view

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, interface-builder, autoresize

I have an application that contain UITabBar and UINavigationBar that looks like this:

[image: First time, intended outcome.. perfect]

Inside the view, I have 2 subviews that occupy top half (red color) and bottom half (green color) equally, inside this 2 views, I have an UIImageView (or UIButton that I assign the background image, I have tested both objects). I assign the position and autoresize value using interface builder and everything looks exactly correct when I first present the view controller, thus showing the view that contains the two subviews.

However, when I navigate to other tab in the tab bar, or using the navigation controller, and go back to the particular view again, both the UIButton goes awry.. inside viewDidAppear, the size no longer correct (the height becomes double), and the UIButton on the 2nd view has Y that is so huge it went out of screen

[image: second and consecutive show... awful]

I have been debugging and tweaking the properties for the whole day, but can't understand what went wrong. I noticed that if I do not check the [Autoresize subviews] checkbox for both the UIViews (red and green views), the layout is perfectly intact and the problem is gone. However, this is not the intended behavior as I'd like the UIButton (together with its backgroundImage) be stretched and grow dynamically on iPad and 4" screen devices..

Attached is my setting for the first subview (red view), the settings for the second view (green view) is either the same, or is locked to the mirrored edge. Thanks in advance!

[image: root view settings]

[image: top view settings]

[image: top UIButton / UIImageView settings]

Comment: since it works so well on first time showing the screen, everytime I navigate to other UIViewController, I'll release the offending VC's view and set it to nil.. it is working that way albeit not an elegant solution...

Comment: note for self:
debug view hierarchy easier with UIView's recursiveDescription
http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/debugging-with-gdb-print-object-and-uiview-recursivedescription.html

Answer (score 0):

Set your images as Button foreground not Button background. Image as button background will stretch but image as button foreground will not.

or set your images to be not stretchy using below code

```
//For image as background    
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//For image as foreground
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work... I tried changing the UIButton to UIImageView but it also doesn't work... one thing that is wierd is on second and subsequent view, the top view did expand to cover the entire screen. I set the bottom view as transparent and see the red covering whole screen, it doesn't happen on first time clicking the tab that contains the view though :(

Comment: @Zennichimaro, try setting ContentMode on Button's UIImageView

Comment: @Zennichimaro, how did you go with this ?

Comment: it isn't working either.. It is wierd, the first view grew to the longer to the bottom and along stretch the UIButton inside.. the second view grew longer to the bottom and along stretch and placed the UIButton a lot lower.. I started to hate AAPL and wished MSFT or BBRY had won the phone war..

Comment: Hey dude, did you set the appropriate properties of 2 subviews (top/bottom) which has sub-subviews(UIButton image) ? I think you are just setting the properties on sub-subviews(UIButton image) and not the subviews(top/bottom). I think those are the ones which get stretched.